# How to connect to a WCF service with wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding, wcf-wshttpbinding

I have hosted a WCF service wsHttpBinding. Then i have created a windows form application to access WCF services as a client application. Client application can invoke WCF services in local machine since credentials are defined as follows by defualt.

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                    realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                    algorithmSuite="Default" />
```

but when i try to run same application on different PC on same network, there will be an authentication fail since its use WINDOWS credential type.
So how can i authenticate other client PCs with wsHttpBinding  over netowrk or internet?
Do i have to use a Certificate or Custom security token and how?

This is my web.config of WCF service

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MyWCFService.CenService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyWCFService.ICenService"/>
      </service>
      <!--<service name="CenService.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyWCFService.IMyService"/>
      </service>-->
     </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You will need to use a certificate.

Comment: Well i'm new to WCF
How to use a certificate? any tutorial ?

Comment: On the same network a certificate should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a service endpoint identity into your service configuration:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyWCFService.ICenService">
    <identity>
        <dns value="(server name)" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```